# Why do I get a borrow error when using Option::map, but not when manually matching?

Tags: reference, rust, pattern-matching

I have this working function:

```rust
fn clear_job(state: State<MyState>) -> Option<String> {
    let mut guard = state.job.lock().unwrap();
    let maybe_job: &mut Option<Job> = &mut *guard;
    // Job is not Copy nor Clone

    match maybe_job {
        None => None,
        Some(job) => match job {
            Job::InProgress { .. } => Some("Can't clear in progress job".into()),
            _ => {
                *maybe_job = None;
                Some("Job cleared".into())
            },
        },
    }
}
```

I return `None` if I have `None` and `Some` if I have `Some`, which is… exactly what `Option::map()` is !

I tried to rewrite this function:

```rust
fn clear_job(state: State<MyState>) -> Option<String> {
    let mut guard = state.job.lock().unwrap();
    let maybe_job: &mut Option<Job> = &mut *guard;

    maybe_job.as_ref().map(|job| match job {
        Job::InProgress { .. } => "Can't clear in progress job".into(),
        _ => {
            *maybe_job = None;
            "Job cleared".into()
        },
    })
}
```

This gets me this error:

```
error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `maybe_job` but it is already borrowed
   --> src/main.rs:113:28
    |
113 |     maybe_job.as_ref().map(|job| match job {
    |     ---------          --- ^^^^^ closure construction occurs here
    |     |                  |
    |     |                  first borrow later used by call
    |     borrow occurs here
...
116 |             *maybe_job = None;
    |              --------- second borrow occurs due to use of `maybe_job` in closure
```

I kinda understand why the error is there; what I don't understand is how I don't get an error in the `match` version, because semantically I'm doing the same thing: reading into `maybe_job`, getting a borrow on `job` (so supposedly on `maybe_job` too), but still writing into `*maybe_job`.

Why am I allowed in the first version but not in the second? Is there a way to use `Option::map` in this situation?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: Assuming I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you might find `filter` and `take` methods useful: [filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.filter), [take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take). Whether or not using them will be more readable is another matter, though.

Answer (score 1):

> I kinda understand why the error is there; what I don't understand is how I don't get an error in the `match` version, because semantically I'm doing the same thing: reading into `maybe_job`, getting a borrow on `job` (so supposedly on `maybe_job` too), but still writing into `*maybe_job`.

In the match case, the compiler helps you out by dropping the borrow on `job` before you write to `*maybe_job`. You can test this yourself - use `job` after you do `*maybe_job = None`, and you'll explicitly borrow `job` for too long, and the compiler will error.

In the `map` case, the borrow which is the argument to the closure `|job|` is an immutable borrow on `maybe_job`. Accessing a variable from a closure is also a borrow (of the variable in the stack) so trying to assign to `*maybe_job` requires taking a mutable borrow on an already borrowed value.

The reason the compiler allows one and not the other is simply a question of how complex the analysis can be - to automatically drop the borrow in `|job|`, the compiler would have to detect and ensure that `maybe_job.as_ref()` is the only borrow on `maybe_job` - which is very tricky. What happens if you do `maybe_job.as_ref().my_function().map(...)` - and `my_function()` copies the immutable reference?